# Authentication and files request

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I made a restricted area in a website and I want to display my files stored in a specific onedrive folder. So I need to get informations these files (every file has a public link so it can be viewed without being logged in in Microsoft).

Simplyfing I need that people entering restricted area retrieve informations about files on behalf of my account: I don't need any of their information nor theri files; just grant them access to specific files in a folder informations.

I read Microsoft documentation (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/onedrive-concept-overview,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online) and some SO thread ([Get Sharepoint online file structure into json file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131035/get-sharepoint-online-file-structure-into-json-file-using-javascript)) but or I have to authenticate from Microsoft interface

I tried js following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v7.2/OneDrive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function launchOneDrivePicker(){
    var odOptions = {
            clientId: "<?php echo $data['client_id']; ?>", // my client id 
            action: "query",
            multiSelect: true,
            advanced: {},
            success: function(files) { console.log(files) },
            cancel: function() { alert('cancel') },
            error: function(error) { console.log(error) }
    };
    OneDrive.open(odOptions);
  }
</script>
```

as well as url

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<?php echo $data['client_id']; ?>&response_type=token&scope={the scopes}&redirect_uri={my app redirect}
```

I actually would expect to have a method to do a remote authentication so I can serve files list in my page

Answer (score 0):

To connect to Graph API you need to follow the Oauth Flow (which works with token).
This implies having authenticated your application in the OneDrive account you want to retrieve the information from.

Depending on the langage you use, there are several SDK you can use to have "the authenticating method" you expected:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/

For example, there is a pretty good sample project using OneDrive in the Java SDK:
https://github.com/cbales/onenote-content-push-java-graph-sample

Comment: Thank you for reply, link to resources was very useful! But actually I noticed I didn't explain that well problem (just edited the thread): I need to display on a specific website (so we don't confuse my app with Microsoft app) page informations about files stored in my onedrive folder; so I need website to login on my behalf. I think this could be the solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0; I'll update if I'll be successfull